# How to import package.json in TypeScript?

Tags: json, typescript

I'm trying to import my package.json file in TypeScript and it doesn't seem to work. Specifically, I'm just trying to import it so that I can access the name and version properties for a log statement. Something like:

```
import * as pjson from '../package.json';
// other code here
log.info(`${pjson.name}:${pjson.version}` started on port ...);
```

We have this same syntax elsewhere in other projects that use Node/Babel, but I'm trying to introduce some TypeScript around these parts. Elsewhere we'd do something like:

```
import { name, version} from '../package.json';
```

That doesn't work here however. I followed the instructions at https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-d-ts which at least made the error on my import statement go away, but now when I try to access properties I get the following error:

```
src/index.ts(20,21): error TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'typeof import("*.json")'.
src/index.ts(20,35): error TS2339: Property 'version' does not exist on type 'typeof import("*.json")'.
```

Is there a way to fix this, or do I just have to hardcode these values somewhere (rather than dynamically retrieving them from package.json)? Maybe I can declare a type for `import("*.json")` somehow with these properties defined on it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Since TypeScript 2.9 you can import JSON files as described here:
[typescriptlang documentation 2.9#json](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#new---resolvejsonmodule), for this you need to enable the "resolveJsonModule" option in your tsconfig.json.

You need typescript version 2.9 in your project:

`npm i typescript@latest --save` or `yarn add typescript`

if you are building the typescript files from the command line with `tsc`, you will need to install the latest typescript version globally:

`npm i -g typescript@latest` or `yarn global add typescript`

if you are building your project with `webpack` and `webpack-dev-server` you need to make sure that `json` files are hosted in the `webpack-dev-server` context as static files. And even if you hosted them, you can't `import` json files in the web environment like this, you would need to load the `json` file with an `ajax` request and parse the response with `JSON.parse`.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. The only thing to note is that I had to include ***BOTH*** the resolveJsonModule option as well as esModuleInterop. Once I set those both to true it finally worked for me.

Comment: Adding resolveJsonModule to the tsconfig.json worked for me

Answer (score 76):

How to import *.json ?

As already answered you need Typescript >= 2.9 and the following settings in `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "resolveJsonModule": true,
  "esModuleInterop": true,
  "module": "commonjs"
}
```

But there are restrictions:

- You must compile to CommonJS
- All your imported JSONs must reside under the `"rootDir"`

Unfortunately the `"rootDir"` is very often a folder *beneath* package.json like './src' and things would fail.

So:
How to import package.json ?
You can `require` it:
`const pjson = require('../package.json')`;

If you use npm.start: [you don't need to :](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#packagejson-vars)

> The package.json fields are tacked onto the npm_package_ prefix. So, for instance, if you had {"name":"foo", "version":"1.2.5"} in your package.json file, then your package scripts would have the npm_package_name environment variable set to “foo”, and the npm_package_version set to “1.2.5”. You can access these variables in your code with process.env.npm_package_name and process.env.npm_package_version, and so on for other fields.

Comment: Upvote for including issue with package.json being outside the rootDir.

Comment: Thanks for the "you don't need to" insight!

Comment: Note that the environment variables also work for those of us using yarn (the field names are still prefixed with "npm_package_").

Comment: "process.env.npm_package_version" - was a great solution for me. That's amazing I didn't know that was possible.

Comment: env variable was the best solution, thanks man!

Comment: Problem with package.json being outside of rootDir solved by setting "rootDir": "./" and "baseUrl": "./src" in tsconfig.json

Answer (score 49):

npm exports `package.json` attributes as env vars with the the prefix `npm_package_` as described in [npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#packagejson-vars)
So if you're using npm you can get the version as `process.env.npm_package_version`

Comment: not in case of Vite! 

Comment: When running from under the VSCode debugger, there are no variables with the prefix: "npm_..."

Comment: I noticed that custom and many other package values don't appear attached to the environment variables.

Answer (score 11):

Typescript should be able to do it as follows:

```
import * as pack from "../package.json"

// access name and version like this:

console.log(pack.name);
```

Check out the third grey box under Support for well-typed JSON imports.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2018/05/31/announcing-typescript-2-9/#json-imports

Comment: The import name should not be "package" because it will return the following error: TS1213: Identifier expected. 'package' is a reserved word in strict mode. Class definitions are automatically in strict mode.

Comment: `import * as pack from '../package.json';` should work

Answer (score 11):

1. Ensure tsconfig.json compiler options contains:

   `"resolveJsonModule": true,
   "esModuleInterop": true,
   "module": "commonjs"`
2. Import package.json with **typings**

   `import * as pack from '../package.json';`