# Can I refer my react.js project version in my index.html?

Tags: reactjs, build, version

I have a React project that I control my versions and update it on package.json. Is it possible to refer to that tag inside this json into the index.html so when I build my react for production it can be inserted into the final html file? Something like this:

```html
<html>
   <body>
      ...
      <script src="index.hash.js?v={package.json version}" />
   </body>
</html>
```

I searched for commands with npm run build but I wasn't able to find anything in that sense

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can "read" your `package.json` file using the answer similarly to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50822310/how-to-import-package-json-in-typescript) and then render it as you wish using a React component.

*Disclaimer*: Be careful to not expose your `package.json` file (make it public) as it will pose a security threat.

Comment: I understand that I can import the package.json and use it inside javascript, but I want to refer it on the HTML file to, for example, set  a <meta /> tag directly on the html file. Something like <meta version="$package.version" /> or <script src="script.hash.js?v=$package.version" />